# Countdown timer using DateTime.Parse without defined date

Tags: c#, datetime

I am writing a bot that gives a countdown to a specific day and time everyweek. In this case  we will say today is Friday. I want to get the countdown till Saturday at 8. The problem with my current format is that it has a defined date. How can I have it work for every Saturday without a defined date for `DateTime.Parse`? If I cannot do it that way, what is a good alternative?

```
        DateTime dt;
        TimeSpan t;
        string countDown = "";

        dt = DateTime.Now;
        dt.DayOfWeek.ToString();

        if (dt.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Friday")
        {
            //Get these values however you like.
            DateTime productLaunchDateTime = DateTime.Parse("02/25/2017 08:00:00 PM");
            DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;

            //Calculate countdown timer.
            t = productLaunchDateTime - startDate;
            countDown = string.Format("Release in {0} Days, {1} Hours, {2} Minutes, {3} Seconds", t.Days, t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this post. Quartz is what you looking for. Also you can check task scheduler for simple solution.

[How to execute code at a given time every day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665525/how-to-execute-code-at-a-given-time-every-day)